# Distributing an exe file compiled with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2013 to compile my C++ project and distribute it to some friends.

I have tried compiling it with Runtime Library set to /MD and having them install "[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)", but it keeps giving the same error message "The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer". I checked an MSVCP120.dll is in their System32 directory.

I also tried to compile it with Runtime Library set to /MT, but when they start the program it just stops responding.

I am just grabbing the exe out of my Release directory. Is there another step I should be taking? Not sure what is causing the issues otherwise. Both exe's work perfectly on my computer, just not on theirs.

Forgive me since this question seems to be asked a lot, but the answers I have found all involve installing "[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)" which we have already tried.

Thanks in advanced for any advice.

Comment: Are you building a 32 bit or 64 bit binary?

Comment: I am building a 32 bit binary, but I am installing 64 bit for Redistribute Package, that must be the issue. I'll try fixing that. Any ideas why the problem happens with I compile with /MT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you install the 32-bit redistributable, it should work.

I wonder if there is some other bug that is causing the `/MT` static version to not work. Unclear with the amount of information given, but that would be my thought.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the 32-bit redistributable and now it gets me past the error for the DLL file, but it now stops responding much like what happens when I compile with /MT.

Is there anything else I can show to help debug the other issue?

Comment: @Danikar If you can isolate it and show some code, that would help. You can step through it with the debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: I figured it out. It has nothing to do with visual studio, the target platform was having an OpenGL error. Thank you for your help. heh.